# Mongo Copy Database Collect Exist Error

Tags: mongodb, collections

I am trying to copy a database from a remote host over to the current database. I am using this command:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.copyDatabase("olddb", "newdb", "xx.xx.xx.137", "user1", "abc123");
```

But I am getting this error:

```
{
    "done" : true,
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "failed to create collection \"newdb.email_batches\": collection already exists"
}
```

Except the collect does not exist. What could I be doing wrong in this command?

Comment: Are you copying a database with a sharded collection?  The command looks right to me according to the documentation.

Comment: No, its a replicaset and I am transferring between primaries.

Comment: 1: have you double-checked that the collection definitely doesn't exist? 2: have you double-checked that the user account has sufficient permissions to write to newdb?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was different database versions. The DB I was on was Mongo 3.0 and the database I was trying to transfer from was 3.2

What is very strange about that is the command copyDatabase as functionaliy for transferring data from 2.6 to 3.2, yet for some reason does not work with 3.0.